# I want to add scrolling UIView just above the centre of UISlider indicator

Tags: ios, uislider

UIView is scrolling with indicator of UISlider on sliding. But the     UIView's centre is not just above the indicator of UISlider. When I sliding UISlider the UIView is shifted left or right of indicator.

I want to make like this image.

[image]

Comment: Just change your view’s center as long as your slider moves.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example you may be interested in .

```
@interface MyUISlider : UISlider
@end

@implementation MyUISlider
UIButton * button;
- (void)awakeFromNib{
[super awakeFromNib];
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];

  [self addSubview:button];
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
self.maximumValue = 10;
self.minimumValue = 0;
self.continuous = NO;
}

-(void)updateLabel{
[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (NSInteger)self.value ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
- (CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value: (float)value{
  CGRect myvalue =  [super thumbRectForBounds:bounds trackRect:rect value:value];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(myvalue.origin.x-10, myvalue.origin.y - 60, 50, 50);
 [self updateLabel];
 return myvalue;
 }
 @end
```